# How to find a mistake in my Merge Sort implementation?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, merge, mergesort

I try to write a merge sort algorithm and I don't see where is a mistake. Can you show me what I have done wrong? Or suggest some useful resources/practice with algorithms?

```
public class MergeSort {

private int[] auxArray;

public void sort(int[] array)
{
    auxArray = new int[array.length];
    sort(array, 0, array.length - 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
      }

}

private void sort(int[] array, int begin, int end)
{
    if( begin >= end) return ;

    int middle = begin + (end - begin) / 2;

    sort(array, begin, middle);
    sort(array, middle + 1, end);
    merge(array, begin, middle, end);

}


private void merge(int[] array, int begin, int middle, int end)
{

    int i = begin;
    int j = middle + 1;

    for (int k = begin; k <= end; k++) {
        auxArray[k] = array[k];
    }

    for (int k = begin; k <= end; k++)
    {
        if(i > middle) array[k] = auxArray[j++];
        else if(j > end) array[k] = auxArray[i++];
        else if(array[i] >= array[j])
        {
            array[k] = auxArray[j++];
        }
        else
            array[k] = auxArray[i++];
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    MergeSort sort = new MergeSort();

    int[] array = new int[] {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5 ,4, 3, 2 ,1};

    sort.sort(array);

}
}
```

Comment: Would you show us a before/after dataset to explain what it does presently? What makes you say it is not working?

Comment: I would suggest tracing what happens when `end` is equal to `begin+1`. In other words, what happens when there's exactly 1 item in the array.

Comment: After assiging `array` to `auxArray` at the beginning you don't need to pass the `array` parameter in any of the `private` methods, use `auxArray` there.

Comment: (Use [System.arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) instead of open coding (partial) array copies.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In merge(), change

```
        else if(array[i] >= array[j])
```

to

```
        else if(auxArray[i] >= auxArray[j])
```